# PHP won't echo XML child

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml

Here is my code

```
    <form method="post">
  <input name="hash" type="text" id="hash" style='width: 30%;'/>
    <input name="Crack!" type="submit" value="Crack!" onfocus="if(this.blur)this.blur()"/>
</form>

    <?php
 if(isset($_POST['Crack!'])){
  $hash = $_POST['hash'];        

     $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://gdataonline.com/qkhash.php?mode=xml&hash=$hash");

  $status = $xml->data->status; 
    if ($status = "Success"){
     $plain = $xml->data->result;
      }elseif ($status = "Hash not found"){
      $plain = "Not Found"; }     

?>
 <table>
 <tr>  
 <td><?php echo "gdataonline.com: "; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo "$plain"; ?></td>
 </tr>
 </table>

<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($xml);
echo "</pre>"; 

 } //if submit

 ?>
```

For some reason I can't get it to echo $plain, at all. Its as if it can't even read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rob, if you want people to even understand your question you have to make an effort instead of just posting a huge chunk of irrelevant code and ask "why does *this* not work?"

So I did your homework, I figured out what the script was doing and fetched an [example XML document](http://gdataonline.com/qkhash.php?mode=xml&hash=098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6). As it turns out, you got the hierarchy wrong. Also, this is unrelated but you are using [assignment operators](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) instead of [comparison operators](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). In other words, your `if`s don't test anything, the first one just sets `$status` to "Success".

The relevant portion should be something like this:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file("http://gdataonline.com/qkhash.php?mode=xml&hash=$hash");

switch ($data->status)
{
    case 'Success':
        $plain = $data->result;
        break;

    case 'Hash not found':
        $plain = "Not Found";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting "$xml->data"? According to [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) there is no member of the SimpleXMLElement object called "data". See that link or the documentation for [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) for numerous examples on using this properly.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be your entire problem, but one definite problem is that you've got two assignments instead of tests:

`if ($status = "Success")`

and

`}elseif ($status = "Hash not found"){`

are both assigning those values to $status instead of testing equality.  You want `$status == "Success"` and `$status == "Hash not found"`

In this case your first test will always succeed (because the return value of assignment is the value assigned, so $status = "Success" will return "Success" which will evaluate to true in an 'if' test, so $plain will always be $xml->data->result, even if the status wasn't really success.

Comment: You're right, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks! But again I still have the same problem, but it was still necessary, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
<form method="post">
  <input name="hash" type="text" id="hash" style='width: 30%;'/>
    <input name="Crack!" type="submit" value="Crack!" onfocus="if(this.blur)this.blur()"/>
</form>

    <?php
 if(isset($_POST['Crack!'])){
  $hash = $_POST['hash'];        

<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://gdataonline.com/qkhash.php?mode=xml&hash=$hash")

if(!xml)
{
 echo "hash not found";
 // return false; // not function so cant return false ignore it
}

$plain = $xml->result;

?>


<table>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo "gdataonline.com: "; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo "$plain"; ?></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```